# Should i hash a users facebook / twitter / other id?

Tags: database, facebook, twitter, authentication, hash

If im running a website that uses social logins, is it neccessary or good in any way, to hash facebook / twitter / google / linkedin user ids when storing in my database?

EDIT: Yes it is true that i wont be able to use it while stored, but keep in mind i will have the actual id when the user is logged on, stored in a temporary session once i confirm the hashes match. Was wondering if it needed to be hashed when stored because in many cases if the database is compromised, it will reveal information about the users...

Comment: Not able to get what you are asking for?

Comment: @SatishPandey Put in the simplest way: Im asking if i should treat a social id as sensitive.

Comment: You must. If you are planning to store the social ids in your database please notify users before so that they are aware of that.